# Using private mutable collections of a covariant type

Tags: scala, covariant

I have a covariant Scala type `Thing[+B]`. The implementation uses an internal mutable queue:

`private val queue : AsyncQueue[B]()`

AsyncQueue is a custom mutable queue implementation, with special properties which I can't easily implement in an immutable version. Because it's mutable, AsyncQueue is invariant. So I can't use it in my covariant type `Thing`.

Since `queue` is private, I can guarantee the correctness of my code: e.g. I won't try to assign `queue` to a reference of type `Queue[Any]`. How can I make this work, keeping `Thing` covariant in `B`, without using casts?

(The solution with casts is to declare an `AsyncQueue[Object]` and cast objects on enqueue/dequeue, which is very ugly.)

**ETA**: I understand type covariance, and I understand why I shouldn't be able to declare an AsyncQueue of a covariant type, or make AsyncQueue itself covariant. My question is how to design this code to avoid using casts everywhere.

Comment: This sounds like the exact use case that led the designers of java's generics to put variance declarations at the point where objects are used, rather than where they are declared.

Comment: What are the methods on `Thing` that make use of `queue`?

Comment: `AsyncQueue` is a bounded Future-based queue. One method calls `queue.enqueue` which returns a Future that completes when the item is enqueued (waiting while there is no room in the queue). Another calls `queue.dequeue` which returns a Future that completes when an item is dequeued (waiting while the queue is empty). These methods let me build a Future-based state machine that pauses while the queue is full.

Comment: Where are the `B`s that are going into `queue` coming from? Can you give an example of where you have to use the casts.

Comment: The `B`s are coming from the user (i.e. via `Thing`'s public API) and are pushed into the queue. If I declare an `AsyncQueue[AnyRef]` then I have to cast dequeued values from `AnyRef` back to `B`.

Comment: It really sounds like `B` shouldn't be covariant in `Thing`. It sounds like `B` is being used in a contravarient position in `Thing` and shouldn't compile. Could you please expand your question with actual code. I'll post an answer that could be some use shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your member immune to the variance check by making it `private[this]`, according to [the spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#variance-annotations).

```
scala> trait Thing[+A] { def next(): A }
defined trait Thing
```

expectedly,

```
scala> class Thingie[+A](implicit t: ClassTag[A]) extends Thing[A] { val as = mutable.ArrayBuffer.fill[A](10)(t.runtimeClass.newInstance.asInstanceOf[A]) ; private val it = as.iterator ; def next() = it.next() }
<console>:12: error: covariant type A occurs in invariant position in type => scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[A] of value as
       class Thingie[+A](implicit t: ClassTag[A]) extends Thing[A] { val as = mutable.ArrayBuffer.fill[A](10)(t.runtimeClass.newInstance.asInstanceOf[A]) ; private val it = as.iterator ; def next() = it.next() }
```

but

```
scala> class Thingie[+A](implicit t: ClassTag[A]) extends Thing[A] { private[this] val as = mutable.ArrayBuffer.fill[A](10)(t.runtimeClass.newInstance.asInstanceOf[A]) ; private val it = as.iterator ; def next() = it.next() }
defined class Thingie
```

and

```
scala> class X
defined class X

scala> val xs = new Thingie[X]
xs: Thingie[X] = Thingie@49f5c307

scala> xs.next
res1: X = X@4816c290
```

Answer (score 3):

You need `@uncheckedVariance`:

```
import scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance

class A[T] {}
class B[+T] {
  val a: A[T @uncheckedVariance] = null
}
```

Even the Scala standard library makes use of `@uncheckedVariance`, notably in allowing the invariant mutable collections to inherit from covariant traits.

Comment: I could only accept one answer, but I was glad to learn from yours too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If `B` is covariant in `Thing[+B]` then you will not be able to have `B` in a contravariant position in `Thing`, i.e.

```
def put(b:B) {...} // will fail to compile, can't use a covariant type in this position
```

But it is possible to make two interfaces for `Thing`, one where the type is used in covariant positions and one where it is used in contravarient positions, as in the following:

```
trait ThingProduce[+B] {
  def get: B 
}
trait ThingConsume[-B] {
  def put(b: B)
}

class Thing[B] extends ThingConsume[B] with ThingProduce[B] {
  private val queue = new scala.collection.mutable.Queue[B]

  def put(b: B) {queue.enqueue(b)}
  def get: B = queue.dequeue

  def both(b: B): B = ???
}
```

So that with the class hierarchy:

```
class Animal
class Mammal extends Animal
class Dog extends Mammal
```

The following can be done:

```
val mammalThing: Thing[Mammal] = new Thing[Mammal]{}
val dogConsumer: ThingConsume[Dog] = mammalThing
val animalProducer: ThingProduce[Animal] = mammalThing
```

But not:

```
val dogConsumer: ThingConsume[Dog] = animalProducer
//or
val animalProducer: ThingProduce[Animal] = dogConsumer
```

Thus `Thing[B]` can be seen to be both covarient and contravariant, but only for certain members.